# Where do hash table's keys exist?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash

A hash table is a data structure that can map keys to values. Given a key, hash function will calculate then tell us the index of the slots/buckets which storing the value. If multiple keys map to a same slot, it might start a linked list from this slot. If there's no enough slots for values, it will do a resizing operation to find a bigger space.

1. Is the first level of a hash table's buckets always an array?
2. Where are the keys stored? Or is it the case that it doesn't have to store the keys every time hash function takes a key and calculates the position?
3. In Ruby language, does a hash object such as `{:name => "Wix", :age => 18}` count as a hash table? If it does, I need the answer of question 2.

Comment: Ruby's `Hash` class uses a hash table internally. The hash table itself is defined in [st.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/st.c). I can highly recommend the book [Ruby Under a Microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) which dedicates a whole chapter to Ruby's hash table.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. I've bought this books a few days ago, I'll read it.

Comment: @Stefan: "Ruby's Hash class uses a hash table internally." – That's not true. The Ruby Language Specification does not prescribe any particular implementation strategy. Rubinius, for example, uses a Trie, not a Hash Table, and that is perfectly legal.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, you're right. When I said "Ruby", I was referring to MRI / YARV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ruby name *Hash* is somewhat misleading. To most developers, they are actually *maps*, meaning you give them a value and they give you another associated value. The fact that they are *hash*maps is really just an implementation detail that makes them fast, and it is in fact the same principle of hashsets, which, given a value, just tell you if the value is in the set or not.

To simplify it a bit, imagine this:

## Storing

You have an array of 10 elements. You are told to remember that 35 = "some data". You then *hash* the index (35), which I will simplify as just modulo-dividing it by the array length, so the result is `35 % 10 = 5`.

We then store store the data 35 = "some data" at that index, for example as a tuple [35, "some data"].

We then get some more data, 25 = "more data" and 78 = "cool stuff". So again, we hash the keys and get `5` and `8`. Storing the second one is easy, we just have to store [78, "cool stuff"] at position 8 in the array.

But storing [25, "more data"] is a problem, because there's already a bucket at position `5`. As you already pointed out, that is solved by storing a linked list. So we go back to the beginning and instead store [35, "some data", nil] for our first value.

To insert `25` we then just change it so that the first element points to the second, and get `array[5] = [35, "some data", <pointer>] -> [25, "more data", nil]`

---

## Accessing

After a while the user wants to know what the value associated with "25" is.

Since we implement a hashmap, we can just *hash* the value, `25 % 10 = 5` and know our pair is stored at position `5`. We then *only* have to iterate a linked list with 2 elements looking for the value `[25]`, and when we find it just take the second value and return it to the user.

---

## In Practice

The above is, of course, an oversimplified example, but it shows the basic idea of how hash-maps operate.

In the real world, the hashing algorithm would, of course, be more complicated than just modulo-dividing, but the idea is the same. The hash of a key is always turned into an index in the array. A good hashing algorithm should be 1. fast and 2. random, to avoid having lots of empty buckets and a few buckets with lots of elements.

Also, our array wouldn't have a fixed length of 10, but be smart about it and try to both save memory by not being excessively big, but at the same time be generous enough with the memory to avoid unnecessary shrinking/growing all the time and keep the buckets reasonably short.

In the best case, you can have a map of a few thousand elements, and to access one you just hash it, which takes the same time independently of the size of the hash, instead of having to iterate all those thousands of elements and comparing each one to the one you're looking for.

---

Regarding your third question, the answer is yes.

As for the second, keys are *stored* in the buckets, but probably just as their hashed values.

I'm not sure how ruby internally stores the buckets, but generally they could be implemented in many ways, as arrays, structs, etc.

Comment: Not exactly; In practice the hash quite long and gets modulo-divided with the length of the hash. Even if two hashes point to position [2] in a 10 element array, the actual hash might be many many bytes in length; long enough to tell the values apart with an insignificantly tiny chance for collisions. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) explains this pretty well :)

Comment: @user3386109 Try opening `irb` and type `0.hash`, `"test".hash` or any other value `.hash` and you'll see that the hashes are actually quite long. As a side note, in Lua there's a [problem with hash collisions](https://kate.io/blog/simple-hash-collisions-in-lua/), where the algorithm is too weak and you can get false positives. Even then, for most use-cases it's still acceptably accurate though.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying ruby Doesn't store them, it may still be doing so  to be completely safe, but that doesn't have to be and is not the case in all implementations (see my previous comment for an example in Lua).

Comment: Tried your suggestion with `irb`, and it appears that the hash is a 64-bit value. That does reduce the odds of collision and makes searching the bucket list faster.  But I would hope that they're being safe about it, and doing a final compare with the actual key. Thanks again.

Comment: I read this in book: "Put a hash function and an array together, and you get a data structure called a hash table." It doesn't mention keys. Does this apply this :  1. When I first time store a key/value, hash function calculated the index, then store the value there; 2. Next time when I use the key to retrieve value, the hash function calculates again, because of 
 hash function's consistency, it will always return same index for same key. So hash table doesn't need to store keys?

Comment: As @user3386109 already said, it's always best to store the keys and do a final compare to be safe (and I suspect ruby does this) but for the lookup itself the key isn't used. That's the point of hashing; if you get a value, you hash it, calculate the index from the hash and look up the bucket, without needing the value itself after hashing it.